# How to make a table with PrettyTable that only has one horizontal line under the title?

Tags: python, prettytable

I want a very minimal table which I attempted as follows:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable, HEADER, FRAME, ALL, NONE

output = PrettyTable(align='l', header=False)
output.title = 'My Table'
output.border = False
output.hrules = HEADER
output.add_row([1, 2, 3])
output.add_row([4, 5, 6])
output.add_row([7, 8, 9])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
  My Table  
 1   2   3  
 4   5   6  
 7   8   9
```

Desired output:

```
  My Table  
-----------
 1   2   3  
 4   5   6  
 7   8   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that style using the following

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable, FRAME, NONE

output = PrettyTable(align='l', header=False)
output.title = 'My Table'
output.hrules = FRAME # horizontal border only at start and end
output.vrules = NONE  # no vertical border

output.add_row([1, 2, 3])
output.add_row([4, 5, 6])
output.add_row([7, 8, 9])

# remove end border
formatted = "\n".join(str(output).splitlines()[:-1])

print(formatted)
```

From what I could tell from the library source there is no way to get the style you want without the `splitlines`/`join` bit at the end to remove the bottom border line.

Comment: Actually that's good enough.  I can live with the rule at the bottom.  I realize now what I was doing wrong.  I tried `output.vrules = False` instead of `output.vrules = NONE`. Thanks.